# How do I add my work google account to my main SO account?

Tags: support, accounts

How do I add my work google account to my main Stack Overflow account? Whenever I go to add a login it just assumes I'm trying to login to my google account with my main google account, and then returns me back to Stack Overflow as if nothing happened.

Comment: I too have noticed this behaviour.

Comment: Hmm. Are you logged into both Google accounts?

Comment: I am not! Shouldn't it ask you though? To pick an existing one... Or add one?

Comment: @AdamLear I went ahead and added my work account to my personal account's chrome session and then revisited the google auth link from my main SO account, and this time it gave me the 2 options, and I successfully added it.

However, I don't think it should work this way! You should get that screen that either allows you to select an existing logged-in account, or add a new one. I've been messing around for days with this (on little brain-power b/c main brain-juice is going towards new job).

Comment: @RudyOnRails Yeah, I agree. Looks like there's a parameter we can pass along for that, though I'm not sure off the top of my head how much work it'd be for us to start doing that for the "add login" path. Could you do me a favor and write up a quick feature-request for this so we can track it easier? Thanks!

Comment: @AdamLear sure, where should I write up the request? I assume there is an area of the site for that type of stuff...

Comment: @RudyOnRails Over on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com) would be great. Tag it [feature-request] and, let's say... [google-openid] and [login]. Thanks again.

Comment: All done. Thanks for consideration Adam.